# Identity API 2.0 Check if user is admin role on View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

Inside the scaffolded partial view `_Layout.cshtml` is defined the app's navigation bar. I'd like to modify it so that some links are only shown if the logged user is `"Admin"`.

Inside the `Seed()` method of my `Configuration.cs` file for migrations, is defined the following:

```
bool AddUserAndRole(ApplicationDbContext context) {
        IdentityResult ir;

        var rm = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
        ir = rm.Create(new IdentityRole("Admin"));

        var um = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));

        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = "admin", FirstName = "System", LastName = "Administrator" };
        ir = um.Create(user, "admin");

        if(ir.Succeeded == false) {
            return ir.Succeeded;
        }

        ir = um.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");

        return ir.Succeeded;
    }
```

As you can see, there is a role called "Admin" and the newly created user is added to that role.

That being said, I've tried several ways inside my `_Layout.cshmtl` to attempt to determine whether the current user is `"Admin"` or not

```
@if(Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name, "Admin")) { }

@if (User.IsInRole("Admin")) { }
```

but none seem effective. How do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
         <li>@Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "Controller", "Action")</li>
    }
```

This worked for me.

Comment: The problem was the password "admin" doesn't work, need to have capital letter and number, so the role wasn't creating as it didnt succeed